# Do I need to unroot my phone to encrypt it?

Tags: encryption, samsung-galaxy-s-5, unrooting

I'd like to fully encrypt my rooted **Samsung Galaxy S5 with Android 5.0** and its SD card.

[This guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/141953/how-to-encrypt-your-android-phone-and-why-you-might-want-to/) says that one needs to unroot ones phone before encrypting it. Is that really needed for my device? And if so - *why*?

Comment: Moved it here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/154032/when-do-i-need-to-enter-my-password-once-i-encrypted-my-phone

Comment: My guess is that if your phone is rooted and encrypted, the encrypted keys are available for any malicious app/ intruder that can gain root access, rendering encryption useless. See this [security stack exchange post](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43737/android-are-locally-stored-encryption-keys-readable-by-attacker-who-gained-root) but i am not sure how that can be avoided if you encrypt and then root !! Maybe, you can post this question there , if you don't get a response here and after deleting it here (cross posting discouraged)

Comment: [This](http://www.droidguiding.com/encrypting-a-rooted-phone-on-android-6-0-1-marshmallow/) says encryption is lost on rooting